# Python pandas doesn't recognize special characters

Tags: python, pandas, special-characters, contains

I am trying to use `df['column_name'].str.count("+")` in python pandas, but I receive

> "error: nothing to repeat"

. With the regular characters the method works, e.g. `df['column_name'].str.count("a")` works fine.

Also, there is a problem with the "^"-sign. If I use `df['column_name'].str.contains("^")` the result is incorrect - it looks like "^" gets interpreted as " " (empty space).

Surprisingly, if I use `.count("+")` and `.contains("^")` on a regular, non-pandas string they work perfectly fine.

simple working example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['Nighthawks+', 'Dragoons'], 'column2': ['1st', '2nd']}, columns = ['column1', 'column2'])
```

When applying `df["column1"].str.contains("^")` one gets "True, True" but is should be "False, False".

And when applying `df["column1"].str.count("+")` one gets

> "error: nothing to repeat"

But then, outside of panda, `"bla++".count("+")` gives correctly the result "2".

Any solutions? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the plus sign:

```
In[10]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['dsa^', '^++', '+++','asdasads']})
df

Out[10]: 
          a
0      dsa^
1       ^++
2       +++
3  asdasads

In[11]:
df['a'].str.count("\+")

Out[11]: 
0    0
1    2
2    3
3    0
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Also when you do `df['a'].str.count('^')` this just returns `1` for all rows:

```
In[12]:
df['a'].str.count('^')

Out[12]: 
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    1
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Again you need to escape the pattern:

```
In[16]:
df['a'].str.count('\^')

Out[16]: 
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    0
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

**EDIT**

Regarding the semantic difference between `count` on a normal string and on a `Series`, [`count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) on a python `str` just does a character count, but [`str.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.count.html#pandas.Series.str.count) takes a regex pattern. The `^` and `+` are special characters which need to be escaped with a backslash if you are searching for those characters

Answer (score 6):

in `str.count()` for special characters you need to use **backslash** for regex patters. (it is explained detaily from @EdChum above).

On the other hand in `str.contains()` we don't need to use backslash for regex patters. Only need to add `regex=False` parameter like `df['a'].str.contains("+", regex=False))` to search and find the string which include special characters.