# Finding cells that contain '+' or '-' sign - Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, search

Trying to see what cells have a '+' sign in them, which cells have '-' and which have both.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"result":['XY: (-Y, 25%)', 'XX: (-5q, 20%);(+18, 20%)', 'XX: (-6q25.3-q27, 11.8Mb, 30%)', 'XX: (-1, 25%);(-10q, 20%)', 'XX: (+5, 20%)']})  
df
```

I tried using `str.contain`

```
gain=df.loc[df['result'].str.contains("+7")]
gain
```

but got an error when trying to pass one of those characters (+ or -)
**error: nothing to repeat at position 0**.
When passing just a number

```
gain=df.loc[df['result'].str.contains("7")]
```

it works great - no errors

Looking for some advice.
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python pandas doesn't recognize special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002776/python-pandas-doesnt-recognize-special-characters)

Comment: Works like magic! Thanks! @BigBen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Trying to see what cells have a '+' sign in them, which cells have '-' and which have both.

you can try:

```
pos=[]
neg=[]
for index in df.index:
    if '+' in df.loc[index,'result']:
        pos.extend([index])
    if '-' in df.loc[index,'result']:
        neg.extend([index])
```

and check if any pos is in neg like:

```
both = []
for item in pos:
    if item in neg:
        both.extend([item])
print(both)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put backslash (escape):

```
gain=df.loc[df['result'].str.contains("\+7")]
```

Comment: Please don't answer a question that is a duplicate. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled